# jqGrid server side sorting with grouping

Tags: sorting, jqgrid, grouping

I have a jqGrid working with grouping. The sorting and paging of the data is made by the server side because I have too many rows, so loadonce is not an option for me.
The problem that I have is that the sidx parameter passed to the server is wrong (it contains the sord parameter too and duplicated sidx), so the server can't find that column in the table.

I've realised if I comment the grouping, sord and sidx return to normal.

This is my code:

```
jQuery("#grid-destinations").jqGrid({
  url:'destinations',
  datatype: "json",
  colModel:[
            {name:'id', hidden:true},
            {name:'cliDestination', jsonmap: 'cliDestination.destinationDesc', index: 'cliDestination', label:'Destination', width:55},
            {name:'orgSub', jsonmap: 'orgSub.subscriptionId', label:'Client', width:55, summaryTpl:''},
            {name:'numCalls', label:'Calls', width:55, formatter:'number', summaryType:'sum'},
            {name:'orgSeconds', label:'Client Minutes', width:55, formatter:'number', summaryType:'sum'},
            {name:'aloc', label:'ALOC', width:55, formatter: 'number', summaryType:'avg', summaryRound: 2, summaryRoundType:'round'},
            {name:'currency', jsonmap: 'orgSub.btsAccount.accountCurrency.currencySymbol', label:'Currency', width:55, summaryTpl:''},
            {name:'saleRate', label:'Sell rate', width:55, summaryType:'avg', summaryRound: 4, summaryRoundType:'round'},
            {name:'income', label:'Income', width:55, summaryType:'sum'},
            {name:'purchaseRate', label:'Cost rate', width:55, summaryType:'avg', summaryRound: 4, summaryRoundType:'round'},
            {name:'cost', label:'Cost', width:55, summaryType:'sum'},
            {name:'profit', label:'Profit', width:55, summaryType:'sum'},
            {name:'percentageProfitIncome', label:'%Prof/Income', width:55, summaryType:'avg', summaryRound: 2, summaryRoundType:'round'}
        ],
  autowidth: true,
  gridview: true,
  viewrecords: true,
  sortname: "cliDestination",
  sortorder: "asc",
  rowNum:100,
        rowList:['All','100','500','1000'],
        pager: '#pager-destinations',
        emptyrecords: "Nothing found to display",
        jsonReader: {
            root: 'content',
            id: 'id',
            repeatitems: false,
            total: 'totalPages',
            records: 'totalElements'
        },
  // grouping
  grouping:true, 
  groupingView : { 
      groupField : ['cliDestination'],
      groupCollapse: true,
      groupSummary: true,
      groupSummaryPos: "header"
  }
}).jqGrid('navGrid','#pager-destinations', {
        edit: false,
        view: false,
        add: false,
        del: false
    }, 
    { }, // edit options
    { },// add options
    { },// del options
    { }, // search options 
    { } // view options
    ).jqGrid('setGridHeight', $("#page").height() - 175);
}
```

I'm grouping data by cliDestination. cliDestination is another object with ID and description, so in the table I see the description because of the jsonmap property.
I want data being ordered by cliDestination.destinationDesc too.

This is sending to the server the param sidx as "cliDestination asc, cliDestination" and sord as "asc".
When I comment the grouping configuration, sidx is "cliDestination" and sord "asc", as it should be.

Any idea of what's happening here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it. I realised that when you are grouping and data is remote, jqGrid changes the sidx to *groupByColumn sord, orderByColumn*.
I had to manage that information in the server to get from sidx orderByColumn and use it to order the data.